# Refactor: Eliminate code duplication in while loop, C#

Tags: c#

What are my options for rewriting following snippet to eliminate code duplication at points A and B:

```
var value = source.GetNext(); // A
while (value != -1) 
{
    sum += value;
    value = source.GetNext(); // B
}
```

Rewriting using mid-loop break is **not acceptable**:

```
while (true)
{
    int value = source.GetNext();
    if (value == -1) break;
    sum += value;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Easy peasy :)

```
while ((value = source.GetNext()) != -1)
{
    sum += value;
}
```